# Impresión desde el servidor

Tags: php, impresión

**PRODUCCIÓN**

Mi sistema desarrollado lo que hace es obtener los datos personales de una persona que va a ingresar a cierto lugar en donde este implementado, en este caso es una clinica.

> Hardware: Impresora de etiquetas **Dymo450** y lector de código de barras para el tipo **CC PDF417**.

**PROBLEMÁTICA**

Resulta que en lo que he desarrollado hago uso de un proceso de impresion por medio del navegador, lo que al principio habia resultado bien, hasta que nos dimos cuenta de que la empresa contratante del servicio realiza el registro de una persona pero no imprime la etiqueta (Cancelando la impresion desde la vista de impresión), que en este caso es el consumible por el cual está enfocado el Software.

**RECOMENDACIÓN**

> En una pregunta anterior, esta fue la respuesta:
>
> *Intenta imprimir desde el servidor sin usar el SDK, mediante comandos. Otra opción es crear tu propio comando con un lenguaje
> compatible con el SDK de la impresora y llamarlo desde tu servidor.
> Gracias a eso me dió una nueva posibilidad de solucionar mi problema*

**SOLUCIÓN**

1. Descargar y copiar la librería de PHP **php_printer.dll** dentro de
   la carpeta de mi servidor local(XAMPP) *C:\xampp\php\ext*.
2. Modificar el fichero **php.ini** del servidor, y adicionar en la sección de extensiones *extension=php_printer.dll*
3. El php_printer.dll debe de ser compatible con la versión actual de PHP [Aquí algunas versiones](https://github.com/gimjudge/php).
4. Código de prueba:

   ```
   <?php
   // '\\\DIRECCION IP DEL EQUIPO\Nombre de la impresora'
   if($handle = printer_open('\\\192.***.*.**\DYMO LabelWriter 450')){
       printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, 'RAW');
       printer_start_doc($handle);
       printer_start_page($handle);
       $line1 = 'Encabezado';
       $line2 = 'Cuerpo del documento1';
       $line3 = 'Cuerpo del documento2';
       $line4 = 'Cuerpo del documento3';

       $font = printer_create_font('Arial', 150, 80, 700, false, false, false, 0);
       printer_select_font($handle, $font);
       printer_draw_text($handle, $line1, 150, 50);

       $font = printer_create_font('Arial', 90, 50, 100, false, false, false, 0);
       printer_select_font($handle, $font);
       printer_draw_text($handle, $line2, 150, 250);
       printer_draw_text($handle, $line3, 150, 350);
       printer_draw_text($handle, $line4, 150, 450);

       printer_delete_font($font);
       printer_end_page($handle);
       printer_end_doc($handle);
       printer_close($handle);
       echo 'Impresion exitosa.';
   }else{
       echo 'No se pudo conectar a la impresora.';
   }
   ?>
   ```

**RESULTADO**

Imprime lo esperado, aunque no he probado con imagenes ni con codigos de barras.

**BARRERAS DE IMPLEMENTACIÓN**

1. Requiero de la IP real del equipo y no la IP del router por la que se conecta el usuario, dado que cuento es con un servidor pago.
2. Requiero reconocer las impresoras que tengo conectadas en el equipo.

**PREGUNTAS**

1. ¿Cómo puedo obtener la IP real del equipo? De esta forma solo obtengo la del router por la que esta conectado. No se mucho sobre redes la verdad.

   ```
   echo "<br>Tu direccion IP es: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";
   ```
2. ¿Si es posible lo que planteo?
3. ¿Cómo puedo obtener las impresoras que estan conectadas al equipo?

**Ayudas de:**

- Rodrigo Avalos
- Pablo Lozano

Comment: Todo ese código PHP corre desde el browser? A mí me parecería peligroso que metiéndome a una página empezara a imprimir cosas sin preguntarme.

Comment: Es verdad lo que dices, pero esta libreria se llamaría al momento de hacer el registro, osea que para que se imprima debe ser ejecutada por el usuario.

Comment: No digo que tu flujo actual va a imprimir sin permiso. Digo que si fuera tan sencillo sería un gran agujero de seguridad. Saber la IP interna que la LAN le asigna a un computador detrás de un router también te permitiría saber los otros equipos conectados a la LAN, y buscar los archivos compartidos, etc.

Comment: Si, es verdad, pero esta es la unica forma que he encontrado para poder imprimir desde el servidor y las barreras que me encontré, ¿qué otra sugerencia podrías brindarme?

Comment: Sólo se me ocurre que el visitante pueda gatillar la impresión desde el browser

Comment: Ese es el problema, porque requiero saber por lo menos si se imprimio o no la etiqueta, yo uso actualmente el método ´window.print()´ y el retorna la vista de impresion pero no tengo forma de como retornar un valor. Así que solo me queda intentar imprimir desde el Server.

Comment: Y por qué necesitas cerciorarte de que la etiqueta se imprimió? No sería más simple mantener un botón que permita al usuario imprimir la etiqueta tantas veces como quiera? Si cancelo a la primera la imprime después :/